# Python - Functions & Execution order

Tags: python

I want to use the bot_create function with a button but I keep getting (on line 20) the problem  "bots not defined" so I moved the function down below the button but got the problem "bot_create not defined". 
I didn't get this problem using C++ and I'm new to Python. How should I arrange the functions?

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp


bots_max = 1000 # Maximum number of bots
bot = []
bot_count = 0

# Menu functions
def save_field():
    pass

# Field functions
def field_clear():
    pass

# Bots functions
def bots_create():
    bot[bot_count] = bots
    bot_count += 1

main = tk.Tk()

field_sides = 600
ctrls_width = 200
main.geometry("800x600")
main.resizable(0, 0)
main.title("Swarm Simulator v1.0")



# Controls menu on left side
button1 = tk.Button(main, text = "Button 1").pack(side = "left", command = bots_create())



class environment:

    def __init__():
        pass

    class wall:
        def __init__():
            pass

# Bots
class bots:

    alive = True

    def __init__():
        alive = True



# Field where bots live
field = tk.Canvas(main, width = field_sides, height = field_sides, bg = "white").pack(side = "right")
for particle in bots:
    print("|")

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Move the `button1 = tk.Button` line below your classes. After that there are other problems in your code you will have to fix.

Comment: You have other problems in this code.  You are treating `bots` like a collection, but it is a class type.  In `bots_create()`, you are modifying `bot_count`, and so it is a local variable, but you are therefore referencing it before assignment.  You want a `global bot_count` as the first line of that function.  Also, your `__init__()` methods do not define a `self` argument, which they must.

Comment: If you want to add something to your `bot` list, just use `bot.append(bots())`. You don't need a separate `bot_count` variable at all.

Comment: Your code would be easier to follow if your class names were singular and your list name was plural.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your code that fixes all the syntactic problems, and so compiles (what I really mean is that my IDE now thinks its ok).  It also runs, but I don't know if it does what you intended.  See my comments in the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp


# moved your class defs up to fix problems with accessing them before they are defined

class environment:

    def __init__(self):   # need a self param here
        pass

    class wall:
        def __init__(self):   # need a self param here
            pass

# Bots
class bots:

    alive = True

    def __init__(self):   # need a self param here
        alive = True

bots_max = 1000 # Maximum number of bots
bot = []
# bot_count = 0  # this no longer does anything.  use `len(bot)` to get the number of objects in the 'bot' list

# Menu functions
def save_field():
    pass

# Field functions
def field_clear():
    pass

# Bots functions
def bots_create():
#    bot[bot_count] = bots   # this will crash as it is referring to a non-existent location in the list
                             # also, your use of "bots" here makes no sense
#    bot_count += 1          # this makes 'bot_count' a local variable, which is not what you want
    bot.append(bots())       # not sure this is what you want, but this creates a new 'bots' object and adds it to the 'bot' list

main = tk.Tk()

field_sides = 600
ctrls_width = 200
main.geometry("800x600")
main.resizable(0, 0)
main.title("Swarm Simulator v1.0")



# Controls menu on left side
button1 = tk.Button(main, text = "Button 1").pack(side = "left", command = bots_create())



# Field where bots live
field = tk.Canvas(main, width = field_sides, height = field_sides, bg = "white").pack(side = "right")
for particle in bot:   # maybe you want to iterate over the 'bot' list instead of the 'bots' type?
    print("|")

main.mainloop()
```

As @khelwood says, it seems that you should swap the use of the names `bot` and `bots` per the way you are using them